# Why does "occasionally" mean "sometimes but not often"? Why does it not mean just "sometimes"?

Tags: meaning, difference

In many dictionaries ([ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/occasionally), [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/occasionally), [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/occasionally))  the definition of "occasionally" is the following:
occasionally - sometimes but not often

I can't understand why there needs to be "but not often".
Why not to write just "occasionally - sometimes"?

Comment: Occasionally conveys a notion of opportunity, i.e. reasons or circumstances for doing something. For example, you may visit someone occasionally, because it's sometimes on your way.

Comment: Some dictionaries use _occasionally_ as part of their definition of _sometimes_. They mean approximately the same, but _occasionally_ may have  slightly more of a sense of 'on rare occasions'.

Comment: Are you asking historically why the words have different meanings?

Comment: @gotube I don't understand what's the difference between "sometimes" and "sometimes but not often". As far as I know, the word "sometimes" itself implies "not often". Do you agree?

Comment: Sometimes, often three times a day, I drink Nescafé.

Comment: @Loviii No, "sometimes" does not imply "not often". "Sometimes" includes a range from "rarely" to "often". So while it's *usually* used to mean something closer to the middle, "sometimes" *can* mean anything from "more often than never" to "less often than always". In contrast, "occasionally" excludes "often".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Did I understand your sentence correctly?: _Sometimes, often three times a day, I drink Nescafé_. = Some days I drink Nescafé. Those days when that happens I do it usually three times a day.

Comment: @Loviii - I drink Nescafe 0, 1, 2 or 3 times in one day.

Answer (score 1):

Good linguistics question.

Basically, from a semantics viewpoint, it does only mean "sometimes". And in fact "sometimes" itself only means [∃(x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification), "there exist(s) some occasion(s)," rather than ¬[∀(x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), "not all the time".

But from here pragmatics takes over, and [the Gricean maxim of quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#Maxim_of_quantity_(content_length_and_depth)) predicts that by virtue of saying only as much as ∃(x), we have implied ¬∀(x), because if it were the case that ∀(x), it would have been more cooperative to provide that information as well.

We would thus expect a similar situation to obtain cross-linguistically. And sure enough, words like French *parfois* "at times", Spanish *a veces* "at occasions", German *manchmal* "some occasion", all imply "not always".

This is not captured by dictionaries because it's not a semantic but a pragmatic level of information.

Now, your question actually concerns "often" rather than "always". But if you reflect, you'll see that the exact same logic applies: you can assume that it's not "often" because if it were, the speaker would have said "often".

Side note: People don't always follow the maxims, either because they're uncooperative or because they can't given the information they have. Hence, suppose I don't know exactly how rarely or frequently a thing happens. I will use "sometimes" as the broader, implying term rather than "often" as the narrower term, even though it may be that "often" would have been more informative, because I can't guarantee it's accurate.